# error while uploading a file to a ftp

Tags: php, file-upload, ftp

I want to upload a csv feed to a public ftp.

I have this:

```
global $_CONFIG;
$host           = $_CONFIG['po']['ftp']['server'];
$username       = $_CONFIG['po']['ftp']['username'];
$password       = $_CONFIG['po']['ftp']['password'];
$ftp_path       = $_CONFIG['po']['ftp']['upload_path'];

$file = $export_file;
$fp = fopen($export_file, 'r+');

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($host);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password);

// try to upload $file
if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $ftp_path, $fp, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
    exit;
} else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
    exit;
}
// close the connection and the file handler
fclose($fp);

ftp_close($conn_id);
```

host,user, password are correct. export file is `D:/some path .csv`

the problem is that the file on the ftp server is called `.upload.somefile.csv` (and it doesn't have the full size).

ftp_path is `/somefile.csv` .

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `ftp_pasv($conn_id,true);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen because of the way FTP works, conflicting with your network layout.

Although you connect out to the FTP server to control the session, by default the server then "calls back" to you with a separate data connection for the transfer. Firewalls, NAT and so on may all interfere with this process under certain circumstances.

Try using FTP's *PASV* mode, using [`ftp_pasv`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-pasv.php), which reverses the direction of the data connection.

Answer (score 0):

A `csv` file should use `FTP_ASCII`, not `FTP_BINARY`

So:

```
  global $_CONFIG;
    $host           = $_CONFIG['po']['ftp']['server'];
    $username       = $_CONFIG['po']['ftp']['username'];
    $password       = $_CONFIG['po']['ftp']['password'];
    $ftp_path       = $_CONFIG['po']['ftp']['upload_path'];

        $file = $export_file;
        $fp = fopen($export_file, 'r+');

        // set up basic connection
        $conn_id = ftp_connect($host);

        // login with username and password
        $login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password);

        // try to upload $file
        if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $ftp_path, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
            echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
            exit;
        } else {
            echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
            exit;
        }
        // close the connection and the file handler
        fclose($fp);

        ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Comment: This only has a potential bearing on line endings and isn't going to cause this problem.

Comment: ok, something is uploading but it is enterning a loop. stocked at 11.467 bytes and still "uploading status" . I've put ftp_pasv($conn_id,true) after if (ftp_fput($conn_id, $ftp_path, $fp, FTP_ASCII)) {
    echo "Successfully uploaded $file\n";
    exit;
   } else {
    echo "There was a problem while uploading $file\n";
    exit;
   }

Comment: ftp_pasv($conn_id,true); after login_result. now is working. Thank you so much!